# unable to delete a file from device storage android

Tags: java, android

I am working on a note application whereby a list view displays notes after storing them in internal storage which is controlled from my Utilities class. I just implemented a delete option in a context menu. The delete option works fine to remove each selected list view item. However when i refresh the list activity or add a new note, the deleted notes keeps re-appearing. Am thinking the file needs to be deleted also from the internal storage but am facing problems doing that.

Main Activity

```
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
      final  Note mLoadedNote = (Note) mListNotes.getAdapter().getItem(info.position);
        mLoadedNote.getTitle();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Delete " +  mLoadedNote.getTitle())
                        .setMessage("are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String  mfileName = getIntent().getStringExtra(Utilities.EXTRAS_NOTE_FILENAME);
                 //my question   if(mLoadedNote != null && Utilities.deleteFile(mfileName)) {
                        ArrayAdapter<Note> arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<Note>) mListNotes.getAdapter();
arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(info.position));
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  mLoadedNote.getTitle() + " is deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "can not delete the note '" + mLoadedNote.getTitle() + "'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
                })
                    .setNegativeButton("NO", null); //do nothing on clicking NO button :P
                alertDialog.show();
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Does the deleted file also appear when you close the app and open the app again ? Also check the value file.delete() returns. If it returns true it means file is deleted and if it returns false means file was not deleted. You should first verify this.

Comment: you need to log/debug the call to `deleteFile()` see what file objects it creates and make sure filename and path are correct

Comment: yeah. it reappears when i restart the app